# Need to print a pattern in one loop with O(n) complexity. I tried the below but not sure of the complexity

Tags: java

I am not sure of the complexity but it's printing the required pattern as it is in 1 loop.

The pattern I need is:

```
****4
***43
**432
*4321
43210
```

A little help is required for the complexity side. Thanks in advance.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s1 = "*****";
    char[] c = new char[s1.length()];
    c = s1.toCharArray();
    String[] Sin = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };
    String append = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        append = append + Sin[Sin.length - i - 1];
        System.out.print(c);
        System.out.println(append);
        c = Arrays.copyOf(c, c.length - 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks bro..i was not able to format it.

Comment: You can't speak of `O(n)` complexity when the is no `n` ! And if `n` is then length of `s1`, why worry about `n=5`?

Comment: Why do you have two nested main() functions?

Comment: @barq sorry for the mistake..

I accidentally  pasted it 2 times

Comment: If you are printing 1 row for each of O(n) numbers and each of those rows contains n characters, you can't do it in O(n). You can write your code with a single for loop which is run O(n) times, but the methods you call in that loop are also O(n) at best.

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the pattern values when you can generate them dynamically , As @YvesDaoust said untill there is no `n` how can you speak of complexity . I suggest you to generate this pattern dynamically then think of complexity

Comment: What about creating the string "*****43210" and printing substrings ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust that is a neat approach to take but just printing the strings in the loop takes O(n^2)

Comment: @MatthewFranglen: I didn't say the opposite, `O(n²)` is optimal. But the OP code is uselessly contrived. On another hand, if you call `n` the size of the pattern, then we are `O(n)`  :-)

Comment: Is it even possible in `O(n)`? Even if one ignores the complexity of print method, then also using any in-built methods would result in `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String nums = "";
    for (int i = 4; i >=0; i--){
        String str = new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", "*");
        nums += i;
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(nums);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think yours solution is much more neat and clean but i guess its not meeting the requirement of O(n)..complexity as substring and replace also carry some complexity.(i guess)

Comment: Modified the answer without substring.

Comment: Printing a string of n characters takes time proportional to n, so your solution is still `O(n^2)`. It doesn't matter if you don't modify the string in any way, just printing n lines of n length is `O(n^2)` complexity.

Comment: If printing takes O(n) then the solution posted in the question is O(n^3) not O(n^2)

Comment: Just because it prints two times does not make it `O(n^3)`. It would have to have a second loop to achieve that. Printing a string of length n, two times, takes 2*n.

Comment: Then how come my solution is not O(n)?

Comment: Substring is not O(1) as of Java 6 though, I believe. My initial answer was with substring, it would be O(n) in Java 5.

Comment: So two print statements would be more efficient than concatening, or use StringBuilder instead. Modified answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
int n=5
for(int i=1,k=1,j=k,l=0;i<=(n*(n+1));i++){
if(i%(n+1) == 0 && i!=0){
    System.out.println();
    k++;
    j=k;
    l=0;
}
else if(n-j>0){
    System.out.print("*");
    j++;
    }
else if(n-j==0){
    System.out.print(j-l);
    l++;
}    
}
```

}
}

Comment: this solution will work in O(n) complexity. So enjoy my friend.

Comment: @ Atul Please check as your loop is running for n*(n+1) times so your complexity is same as O(n2) .
Thanks for your help.

Comment: After going through all of the comments i guess it is not possible to write this pattern in O(n) complexity  as we need to perform factorial n operations on it.
so the best case would be o(n2) only..(please correct me if am wrong).
I really thanks all of you for your answers and time....